# How to limit file type to be upload?

Tags: uploads

I have a custom page template with a form, that any visitor of the website can upload a file. Now, I want to restrict the file type that will be upload (docx, doc and pdf only) and I limit the file size into 2MB only.

How to do this? I already have a function that the user allowed to upload, but I don't know how to restrict the file type that allowed to be upload. Please help me.

I tried to change

`'post_mime_type' => $file_return['type']`

into this

`'post_mime_type' => 'application/msword,vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document,pdf'`

but still it's not working.

PHP in custom page template

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $firstName = isset($_POST['firstName']) ? $_POST['firstName'] : '';
    $middleName = isset($_POST['middleName']) ? $_POST['middleName'] : '';
    $lastName = isset($_POST['lastName']) ? $_POST['lastName'] : '';
    $email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
    $mobile = isset($_POST['mobile']) ? $_POST['mobile'] : '';
    $locations = isset($_POST['locations_list']) ? $_POST['locations_list'] : '';
    $position = isset($_POST['position']) ? $_POST['position'] : '';
    $message = isset($_POST['message']) ? $_POST['message'] : '';
        if( ! empty($_FILES)){
            $file=$_FILES['resumeFile'];
            $attachment_id = upload_user_file($file);
        }

    $sql=$wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("INSERT INTO resume_databank(submit_time,last_name,first_name,middle_name,mobile_number,email,location,position,message,process_resume,attachment_resume_id) VALUES (now(),'$lastName','$firstName','$middleName','$mobile','$email','$locations','$position','$message','No','$attachment_id')"));
}
```

PHP in functions.php

```
function upload_user_file($file = array()){
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/admin.php');
      $file_return = wp_handle_upload($file, array('test_form' => false));
      if(isset($file_return['error']) || isset($file_return['upload_error_handler'])){
          return false;
      } else {
          $filename = $file_return['file'];
          $attachment = array(
              'post_mime_type' => $file_return['type'],
              'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename($filename)),
              'post_content' => '',
              'post_status' => 'inherit',
              'guid' => $file_return['url']
          );

          $attachment_id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $file_return['url']);

          require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
          $attachment_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attachment_id, $filename);
          wp_update_attachment_metadata($attachment_id, $attachment_data);

          if(0 < intval($attachment_id)){
            return $attachment_id;
          }
      }
      return false;
}
```

Comment: Use [`pathinfo(file_name)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) to get the upload extension, `$pathinfo = pathinfo( $file['name'] ); if( empty( $pathinfo ) || ! in_array( strtolower($pathinfo['extension']), array('jpg','bmp','png') ) ) { return; }` place it in the top of `upload_user_file()` or before calling that func.

Answer (score 1):

This is a full working example with file type and size limits and all the error handling.

Every step is commented. Let me know if you have any more questions.

- You can find all the mime types from [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/mime-types-summary-list/).
- Make sure to check if it's [allowed](https://codex.wordpress.org/Uploading_Files) in WP too.

---

```
// Allowed file types -> search online for desired mime types
$allowed_file_types = array( "image/jpeg", "image/jpg", "image/png" );
// Allowed file size -> 2MB
$allowed_file_size = 2000000;

$upload_errors = '';

// Check if has a file -> this assumes your file input "name" is "uploaded-file"
if ( ! empty( $_FILES['uploaded-file']['name'] ) ) {

    // Check file type
    if ( ! in_array( $_FILES['uploaded-file']['type'], $allowed_file_types ) ) {

        $upload_errors .= '<p>Invalid file type: ' . 
                          $_FILES['uploaded-file']['type'] . 
                          '. Supported file types: jpg, jpeg, png</p>';
    }

    // Check file size
    if ( $_FILES['uploaded-file']['size'] > $allowed_file_size ) {

        $upload_errors .= '<p>File is too large. Max. upload file size is 2MB</p>';
    }

    // No errors -> upload image
    if ( empty( $upload_errors ) ) {

        if ( $_FILES['uploaded-file']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK ) __return_false();

        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );

        // Upload the file -> if you don't want to attach it to post, pass $post_id as 0
        $upload_id = media_handle_upload( 'uploaded-file', $post_id );        

        if ( is_wp_error( $upload_id ) ) {

            // Error uploading the file -> show it
            echo '<p>Upload failed. Please submit again</p>';
        } 
        else {

            // No errors -> show success message
            echo '<p>Upload was successful</p>';
        }
    }

    // Had an error -> show error(s)    
    else {

        echo $upload_errors;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply add an if statement like :

```
    if ( $file["type"] != "application/pdf" ){
        exit;
    }
```

You can add a message in $_SESSION and redirect the url to show for user what is wrong

```
if(session_id() == '') {
    session_start();
}
$_SESSION['error_uplaod'] = '.pdf with 2MB maxsize files is only allowed';
session_write_close();
wp_redirect( $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] );
```

---

in other way if you want to use $mimes :

```
function your_mimes($mimes) {
  $mimes = array('pdf' => 'application/pdf');
  return $mimes;
}
```

you can see list of all types : [here](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml)
then just before and after the upload method add :

```
add_filter('upload_mimes','your_mimes');
```

and :

```
remove_filter('upload_mimes','your_mimes');
```

if you leaved that with out remove it then thats will applied for all uploads in site after executing it .
Hope that help you

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($_FILES['myfile']['size'] <= '2000000') {
    // if file size is not larger than 2MB
    $overrides['mimes'] = [
        'jpg|jpeg|jpe' => 'image/jpeg',
        'gif' => 'image/gif',
        'png' => 'image/png',
    ];
    $uploadResult = wp_handle_upload($_FILES['myfile'], $overrides);
    // use $uploadResult to continue working with your code.
} else {
    // if file size is larger than 2MB.
    // handle with the error below by yourself. it is just example.
    wp_die('Upload file size is too large.');
}
```

Reference: https://rundiz.com/?p=448

In `mimes` array key, you can use multiple file extensions but it must be able to use in regular expression.
From my example: `jpg|jpeg|jpe` means file extension can be one of these the `|` sign means **OR** and the array value is mime type.